# Format number into two decimal places - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Format
21000 into 210.00 or
21123 into 211.23

I've tried
***select to_char(21000,'999.99') from dual;***
but I'm getting ##### as result.

I've also tried ***select to_char(21000,'99999.99') from dual;***
but it formats the number to 21000.00

Comment: Did you actually mean "format 21000 into the decimal number 210, represented as the string 210.00" (with two decimal places)? This is not just a "formatting" problem - you are actually dividing by 100. In "formatting" you don't change the value, just the way it's shown. Or did you mean "show the number 21000 as 210.00, where the dot is a group separator - the number is still the integer twenty-one thousand"? In that case, why are you referring to "decimal places"? Either way you should clarify. One responder so far assumed one of the two answers, but I am not 100% sure that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide by 100:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(value / 100, 'FM990.00') AS formatted_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 21000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21123 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | FORMATTED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 21000 | 210.00 |
> | 21123 | 211.23 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=47b8f64172a36227de3446ed927ab8ac)*